# 32-bit instructions memory in verilog

Tags: memory, verilog, vivado

In the instruction memory, we need internal storage to store the instructions. We need to define a 2D
array to store 64 instructions each with 4 bytes (32 bits). So, define Instruction memory as a new type
which is a 64 × 32 2D array and define signal memory from type Instruction memory.
Then, we need to actually store some instructions (which are 32 bits data) in the signal that we defined
as internal storage.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Module definition
module InstMem (
input [7:2] addr,
output wire [31:0] instruction
);

reg [31:0] memory[63:0];
assign instruction= memory[addr[7:2]];
initial begin
memory[0] = 32'h00007033; // and r0, r0, r0 32'h00000000
memory[1] = 32'h00100093; // addi r1, r0, 1 32'h00000001
memory[2] = 32'h00200113; // addi r2, r0, 2 32'h00000002
memory[3] = 32'h00308193; // addi r3, r1, 3 32'h00000004
memory[4] = 32'h00408213; // addi r4, r1, 4 32'h00000005
memory[5] = 32'h00510293; // addi r5, r2, 5 32'h00000007
memory[6] = 32'h00610313; // addi r6, r2, 6 32'h00000008
memory[7] = 32'h00718393; // addi r7, r3, 7 32'h0000000B
memory[8] = 32'h00208433; // add r8, r1, r2 32'h00000003
memory[9] = 32'h404404b3; // sub r9, r8, r4 32'hfffffffe
memory[10] = 32'h00317533; // and r10, r2, r3 32'h00000000
memory[11] = 32'h0041e5b3; // or r11, r3, r4 32'h00000005
memory[12] = 32'h0041a633; // if r3 is less than r4 then r12 = 1 32'h00000001
memory[13] = 32'h007346b3; // nor r13, r6, r7 32'hfffffff4
memory[14] = 32'h4d34f713; // andi r14, r9, "4D3" 32'h000004D2
memory[15] = 32'h8d35e793; // ori r15, r11, "8d3" 32'hfffff8d7
memory[16] = 32'h4d26a813; // if r13 is less than 32'h000004D2 then r16 = 1 32'h00000000
memory[17] = 32'h4d244893; // nori r17, r8, "4D2" 32'hfffffb2C

end
endmodule
```

```
module instr_memtb(  reg [7:2} addr;  wire [31:0] instruction; InstMem
instant(.addr(addr),.instruction(instruction));
 
initial begin
addr = 6'b000000; // Initial address (will be overridden by force command in simulation)
#100; // Simulate for 100 nanoseconds
        
end endmodule
```

I am struggling to work the force constant. It fetches the instructions but the wave configuration in vivado is all X's and 0's pls help me fix this!!

Answer (score 0):

The way the address is expressed `[7:2] addr`, suggests 8-bit data accessed 4 bytes at a time.  You are storing 32 bit data, so the address to the memory needs to be adjusted in the module like this `memory[addr >> 2]`.  Addressing data should be done in increments of 4.

RTL

```
module InstMem (
  input [7:2] addr,
output wire [31:0] instruction
);

reg [31:0] memory[63:0];
  assign instruction= memory[addr >> 2];
initial begin
memory[0] = 32'h00007033; // and r0, r0, r0 32'h00000000
memory[1] = 32'h00100093; // addi r1, r0, 1 32'h00000001
memory[2] = 32'h00200113; // addi r2, r0, 2 32'h00000002
memory[3] = 32'h00308193; // addi r3, r1, 3 32'h00000004
memory[4] = 32'h00408213; // addi r4, r1, 4 32'h00000005
memory[5] = 32'h00510293; // addi r5, r2, 5 32'h00000007
memory[6] = 32'h00610313; // addi r6, r2, 6 32'h00000008
memory[7] = 32'h00718393; // addi r7, r3, 7 32'h0000000B
memory[8] = 32'h00208433; // add r8, r1, r2 32'h00000003
memory[9] = 32'h404404b3; // sub r9, r8, r4 32'hfffffffe
memory[10] = 32'h00317533; // and r10, r2, r3 32'h00000000
memory[11] = 32'h0041e5b3; // or r11, r3, r4 32'h00000005
memory[12] = 32'h0041a633; // if r3 is less than r4 then r12 = 1 32'h00000001
memory[13] = 32'h007346b3; // nor r13, r6, r7 32'hfffffff4
memory[14] = 32'h4d34f713; // andi r14, r9, "4D3" 32'h000004D2
memory[15] = 32'h8d35e793; // ori r15, r11, "8d3" 32'hfffff8d7
memory[16] = 32'h4d26a813; // if r13 is less than 32'h000004D2 then r16 = 1 32'h00000000
memory[17] = 32'h4d244893; // nori r17, r8, "4D2" 32'hfffffb2C

end
endmodule
```

Testbench

```
module instr_memtb() ;
  
reg [7:2] addr; 
wire [31:0] instruction; 
  
InstMem instant(.addr(addr),.instruction(instruction));

initial begin
  addr = 6'h00; // Initial address (will be overridden by force command in simulation)
  #1;
  $display("ins = %h",instruction);
  addr = 6'h04; // Initial address (will be overridden by force command in simulation)
  #1;
  $display("ins = %h",instruction);
  addr = 6'h08; // Initial address (will be overridden by force command in simulation)
  #1;
  $display("ins = %h",instruction);
end

endmodule
```

Produced On Eda Playground Cadence

```
xcelium> run
ins = 00007033
ins = 00100093
ins = 00200113
```

The testbench vectors access memory as intended for the first few vectors.

Remember that the byte oriented address, delivering dwords (32 bits) skips by 4 each increment (in hex) 0,4,8,C,10,14....